# Proftpd configuration to run ftp/ftes ftps and sftp at the same time on different port

Tags: ftp, configuration, aix, proftpd

I have compile version of proftpd 1.3.4d with ftp, ftps, sftp and mysql authentication.
So far I can have working at the same time on port `210`:  `ftp` and `ftpes` and on port `211` the `sftp`.

```
ServerName                      "ProFTPD self contained package"
ServerType                      inetd
Port                            211
UseIPv6                         off
Umask                           022
User                    nobody
Group                   nobody
allowOverwrite          on
SystemLog                       none

<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
  DenyAll
</Limit>

<Global>
DefaultRoot ~
</Global>

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
       Port 210
       SQLUserWhereClause              " (allowed = 'both' OR allowed = 'ftp') "
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
  <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
        SFTPEngine on
        SFTPLog  none
        Port 211
        SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
        SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
        SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:../etc/ssh/authorized_keys
        SQLUserWhereClause              " (allowed = 'both' OR allowed = 'sftp') "
        SFTPCompression delayed
        MaxLoginAttempts 6
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dso.c>
    LoadModule mod_tls.c
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_tls.c>    
    TLSEngine on
    TLSLog /usr/local/proftpd/var/log/etls.log
    TLSRequired on
    TLSRSACertificateFile /usr/local/proftpd/etc/proftpd.cert.pem
    TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /usr/local/proftpd/etc/proftpd.key.pem
    TLSVerifyClient off
    TLSRenegotiate none
    TLSProtocol SSLv3 TLSv1
</IfModule>
```

This is working what I want to do no wis adding a VirtualHost like this:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
       Port 214
       TLSOptions UseImplicitSSL
</VirtualHost>
```

To have a virtual host accepting only `ftps` when I try the new virtual host it just does not work at all and `ftp` `ftpes` and `ftps` does almost work but can't finish authentication.

My question here is first do you have comment on my config (but that is optional).
No the real question is

**Is what I'm trying to achieve possible and if possible how ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible and here's my config file:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Server Configuration: those parameters cannot be elsewhere
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ServerName                          "ftp daemon"
ServerType                          inetd
UseIPv6                             off

# Bar use of SITE CHMOD by default
<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
        DenyAll
</Limit>

SystemLog                           none
LogFormat                           authentication "%{%F %T}t %P  from: %a to: %{protocol}:%H:%p  user: %U       msg: %S"
LogFormat                           transfer       "%{%F %T}t %P  from: %a to: %{protocol}:%H:%p  user: %U       file: %f        cmd: %m %J"

ScoreboardFile                      /local/proftpd/var/proftpd.scoreboard


TLSProtocol                         SSLv3 TLSv1

<Global>
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Generic Configuration
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    DefaultRoot                         ~
    Umask                               022
    allowOverwrite                      on
    User                                nobody
    Group                               nobody
    ExtendedLog                         /var/log/proftpd_auth.log AUTH,EXIT,SEC authentication
    ExtendedLog                         /var/log/proftpd_xfer.log READ,WRITE transfer
    AuthOrder                           mod_sql.c mod_auth_unix.c mod_auth_pam.c

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # TLS Configuration
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    TLSEngine                                               off
    TLSRSACertificateFile           /usr/local/proftpd/etc/proftpd.cert.pem
    TLSRSACertificateKeyFile        /usr/local/proftpd/etc/proftpd.key.pem
    TLSLog                                                  none
    TLSVerifyClient                                 off
    TLSRenegotiate                                  none
    TLSRequired                                     off
</Global>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    __ _              __   __ _         _____ _____                    __
#   / _| |            / /  / _| |       |  ___/  ___|                  / _|
#  | |_| |_ _ __     / /  | |_| |_ _ __ | |__ \ `--.    ___ ___  _ __ | |_
#  |  _| __| '_ \   / /   |  _| __| '_ \|  __| `--. \  / __/ _ \| '_ \|  _|
#  | | | |_| |_) | / /    | | | |_| |_) | |___/\__/ / | (_| (_) | | | | |
#  |_|  \__| .__/ /_/     |_|  \__| .__/\____/\____/   \___\___/|_| |_|_|
#          | |                    | |
#          |_|                    |_|
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    Port                                    210
    TLSEngine                               on
</VirtualHost>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    __ _         _____                    __
#   / _| |       /  ___|                  / _|
#  | |_| |_ _ __ \ `--.    ___ ___  _ __ | |_
#  |  _| __| '_ \ `--. \  / __/ _ \| '_ \|  _|
#  | | | |_| |_) /\__/ / | (_| (_) | | | | |
#  |_|  \__| .__/\____/   \___\___/|_| |_|_|
#          | |
#          |_|
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    Port                                    214
    TLSEngine                               on
    TLSOptions                              UseImplicitSSL
</VirtualHost>

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   _____  __ _                            __
#  /  ___|/ _| |                          / _|
#  \ `--.| |_| |_ _ __     ___ ___  _ __ | |_
#   `--. \  _| __| '_ \   / __/ _ \| '_ \|  _|
#  /\__/ / | | |_| |_) | | (_| (_) | | | | |
#  \____/|_|  \__| .__/   \___\___/|_| |_|_|
#                | |
#                |_|
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
    <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
        Port                                    211
        SFTPEngine                              on
        SFTPLog                                 none
        SFTPHostKey                     /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
        SFTPHostKey                     /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
        SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys  file:../etc/ssh/authorized_keys
        SFTPCompression                 delayed
        MaxLoginAttempts                6
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: config works, except I additionally needed a
`Port 0` in the main config

Comment: might be possible but if I'm not mistaken, there's no TCP port 0. Might come from the inetd deamon evolving

Comment: `Port 0` disables that server (main config or virtual host), also helped me.
Source: [official documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_Port.html)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, it took me a while to figure out all that. it was a long time ago though.